# Counting comma separated values in TSQL

Tags: csv, sql-server-2008-r2, whitespace

SCHEMA / DATA for TABLE :

```
SubscriberId NewsletterIdCsv
------------ ---------------
11           52,52,,52
```

We have this denormalized data, where I need to count the number of comma separated values, for which I am doing this :

```
SELECT SUM(len(newsletteridcsv) - len(replace(rtrim(ltrim(newsletteridcsv)), ',','')) +1) as SubscribersSubscribedtoNewsletterCount
FROM TABLE
WHERE subscriberid = 11
```

Result :

```
SubscribersSubscribedtoNewsletterCount
--------------------------------------
4
```

The problem is some of our data has blanks / spaces in between the comma separated values, if I run the above query the expected result should be 3 (as one of the value is blank space), how do I check in my query to exclude the blank spaces?

EDIT :

DATA :

```
SubscriberId NewsletterIdCsv
------------ ---------------
11           52,52,,52  
12           22,23
```

I need to get an accumulative SUM instead of just each rows sum, so for this above data I need to have just a final count  i.e. 5 in this case, excluding the blank space.

Comment: I think more complex but optimal way is to create CLR function.

Comment: How about don't store data this way?

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand the question does not involve normalizing the data, I know that's the optimal solution.

Comment: @MurtazaMandvi so why can't you fix that? Put it off and you're just going to have to implement more and more hacks to deal with this data in a different way because you chose to do it wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one solution, although their may be a more efficient way:

```
SELECT A.[SubscriberId],  
  SUM(CASE WHEN Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') = '' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) cnt
FROM  
(
   SELECT [SubscriberId],  
     CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(NewsletterIdCsv, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS String  
   FROM  YourTable
) AS A 
CROSS APPLY String.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
GROUP BY A.[SubscriberId]
```

And the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b807f/2).

Basically it converts your NewsletterIdCsv field to XML and then uses `CROSS APPLY` to split the data.  Finally, using `CASE` to see if it's blank and `SUM` the non-blank values.  Alternatively, you could probably build a UDF to do something similar.

Comment: This works, I will let someone come up with an optimized solution before marking yours as answered :)

Comment: @MurtazaMandvi -- the best others I've seen involve creating UDFs -- guess it depends on the amount of data etc.  Glad I could help and best of luck!

Comment: I've actually added a bit more data i my question, can you take a look at that , the Sum with your query just gives a sum on each row, I need an accumulative count

Comment: sorry my bad, updated the DATA in my EDIT, subscriberid is different now, 11 and 12 and I need accumulative count from both / all

Comment: @MurtazaMandvi -- just remove SubscriberId from the SELECT and GROUP BY: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8ece4/2